# Add attachment to e-mail - php mail

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I created simple code to send e-mails via contact form.

I would like to add button to attach image file and as attachment send with e-mail (use contact form).

**Button**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" accept="image/*" placeholder="">
```

**PHP Code**

```
header("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "to@namedomain.com";
$subject = "Title";

if($name && $email && $message){

 $mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
 $mailheader .= "From: ".$email." \n\r";

 $formcontent = "Subject: $name \n\n $message \n" ;

 if(mail($to,$subject,$formcontent,$mailheader)){
 $json=array("status"=>1,"msg"=>"<p class='status_ok'>Success.</p>");
 }
 else{
 $json=array("status"=>0,"msg"=>"<p class='status_err'>Fail.</p>"); 
 }
}
else{
 $json=array("status"=>0,"msg"=>"<p class='status_err'>All fields required.</p>"); 
}
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

I was trying to look for that but no success. I would like to get something what will be work with my case.
I found something about PHPMailer but I don't understand how I can use it with my case so I would like to stay with my structure.

Comment: *"So what's the problem?"* - You tell us http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and nowhere do I see the `uploadfile` used in the php. This sounds like a "write this for me" question. The complete form is also unknown.